# AngularJS - Ng-Repeat does not update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I am working on a web store using Angular and am trying to clean the code using a service. I would like the service to load a list of items from a REST api and perform functions on those items across a variety of controllers. My problem occurs when I try to populate an ng-repeat statement with the data returned from the REST call - the list is never populated with the items that are fetched. Previously I was using $scope and $apply to ensure that my DOM was updated when the data was returned - is there something similar that I can do within the service?

The service

```
'use strict';
var serv = angular.module('serv', []);
serv.factory('shopService', function() {
    //create the shop client as service varible
    var client = window.ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
        domain: 'xxxxxxx.myshopify.com',
        storefrontAccessToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    });
    var products = [];
    client.product.fetchAll().then((products_complete) => {
        //do things and get the products ready
        products.push(item);
    });

    return {
        products: products
    }
});
```

The controller

```
'use strict';
var serviceApp = angular.module('serviceApp', ['serv']);
serviceApp.controller('CartController', ['shopService', function CartController(shopService) {
    //create a reference to the service variable
    this.products = shopService.products;
}]);
```

And the HTML

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="serviceApp" ng-controller="CartController as cart">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="product in cart.products">
                <div> {{ product.title }} </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The best solution would probably be to change the `client.product.fetchAll()` to be a function that returns `products` instead of only exposing products directly.  What is probably happening is that your `this.products = shopService.products` is being called before the fetchAll promise finishes executing.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this would require me to reload the products each time that a controller accesses the list, and this is the problem that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: So the items in the cart will never change?  Seems counter intuitive, but I'll write up an example of how to only call the `fetchAll` once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make sure the promise finishes running before assigning the products in the controller and avoid running the `fetchAll` more than once.  You can change the service:

```
serv.factory('shopService', function($q) {
    //create the shop client as service varible
    var client = window.ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
        domain: 'xxxxxxx.myshopify.com',
        storefrontAccessToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    });
    var products = [];
    var fetchAllCompleted = false;

    function getProducts() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (fetchAllCompleted) {
            deferred.resolve(products);
        } else {
            client.product.fetchAll().then((products_complete) => {
                //do things and get the products ready
                products.push(item);
                fetchAllCompleted = true;
                deferred.resolve(products);
            });
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    }


    return {
        getProducts: getProducts
    }
});
```

Then in the controller

```
serviceApp.controller('CartController', ['shopService', function CartController(shopService) {
    //create a reference to the service variable
    shopService.getProducts().then(function(products) {
        this.products = products;
    });
}]);
```

That should fix your issues.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right, then you have few workarounds. One is to use `$apply()` in your ajax call,what it will do? Sometimes when a promise is being return , the values are not updated by angular. and it will return an empty obj. By calling `$apply()` you can update the scope. And the 2nd workaround is to call service first and send your request and then make a return function that will return the obj that you just called in above service. concept of Setter and Getter, I use this approach , i use one function to get the data and the other one to retrieve the data.
The last thing you can try out is to wait until the data fetched into your obj, and then return it. when you use your ng-repeat if the service is called each time, `ng-repeat` won't work, first get all the data in a single obj and then call that obj , keeping in mind that you will only call service one time in controller. and that service will return you your data  before ng-repeat.

Answer (score -2):

try to make sure the service is up and running/returning backend data..
then check this example:

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/l7lGPRIs0ZuDWpVK2pX8?p=preview
```

Angular JS

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="animations.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="ngRepeat">
      <div ng-controller="repeatController">
      I have {{friends.length}} friends. They are:
      <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="filter friends..." aria-label="filter friends" />
      <ul class="example-animate-container">
        <li class="animate-repeat"
        ng-repeat="friend in friends">
          [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
        </li>
        <li class="animate-repeat" ng-if="results.length === 0">
          <strong>No results found...</strong>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

JS object:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('ngRepeat', ['ngAnimate']).controller('repeatController', function($scope) {
  $scope.friends = [
    {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
  ];
});
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: The backend is returning data successfully -  I am able to use console.log within the controller and receive the desired output. I have already implemented this solution where the data is stored within the $scope variable of the controller, but my goal with moving the data into the service was to share the information across multiple controllers.

Comment: A static list is not the same thing as a promise.